# The given token is invalid error in EWS OAuth authentication when using personal account

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices, azure-ad-graph-api

I have to get the contacts from Exchange server from any account, so we have used the code from below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth

But it is not working for personal accounts, which is working fine for our organization account. So I have used AadAuthorityAudience property instead of TenantId and changed the scope from EWS.AccessAsUser.All to others. Now authentication got success but getting "The given token is invalid" error while using the token in ExchangeService.

```
var pcaOptions = new PublicClientApplicationOptions {
    ClientId = "77xxxxxxxxxxx92324",
    //TenantId = "7887xxxxxxxxxxxxx14",
    RedirectUri = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf",
    AadAuthorityAudience = AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdAndPersonalMicrosoftAccount};

var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions(pcaOptions).Build();

//var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All" };
var ewsScopes = new string[] { "User.Read", "Contacts.ReadWrite.Shared" };

var authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync();

var ewsClient = new ExchangeService();
ewsClient.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
//ewsClient.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "araj@concord.net");
ewsClient.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);

// Make an EWS call
var folders = ewsClient.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, new FolderView(10));
```

What am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All is the right scope to use. The scope is invalid for personal accounts since they're not supported by EWS.

Comment: Thanks @Alfredo, Actually I tried that scope also but I am getting below error.

"AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope 'EWS.AccessAsUser.All offline_access openid profile' is not configured for this tenant.
Trace ID: 09xxxxxxxxx00
Correlation ID: 80xxxxxxxxxcc1"

And one more thing, I am getting below warning in Azure, I dont have enough permission to verify this. Will it be a problem?

"Starting November 9th, 2020 end users will no longer be able to grant consent to newly registered multitenant apps without verified publishers."

Comment: Are you trying with personal accounts? Those won't work.